# Cell Value Changing Event ,c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in which there are 3 columns; Quantity, Rate and Amount.
The DataGridView is Editable. When I enter a value in the Rate Column then immediately the value should be changed in Amount.

```
Amount=Qty*rate
```

It is happening, but when I click on any other cell, I want that when I enter any value in Rate it should be multiplied with Quantity and be reflected immediately in Amount without changing the cell.

Comment: which event have you tried? try DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged Event

Answer (score 7):

As it was mentioned by Sachin Shanbhag you should use both `DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` and `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` events. In `DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` you should check whether the user is modifying the right cell (*Rate* in your case) and then execute [DataGridView.CommitEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.commitedit.aspx) method. Here is some code.

```
private void YourDGV_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (YourDGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == rateColumnIndex)
    {
        YourDGV.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);                        
    }
}

private void YourDGV_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == rateColumnIndex)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cellAmount = YourDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[amountColumnIndex];
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cellQty = YourDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[qtyColumnIndex];
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cellRate = YourDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[rateColumnIndex];
        cellAmount.Value = (int)cellQty.Value * (int)cellRate.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using CommitEdit, CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged indeed works as expected, it is fired everytime a change occurs on the dirty state (i.e the user changes the string), thanks Dmitry!

Answer (score 1):

I have found no event that can handle the value of cell change properly.

You must convert the editable cell into a Textbox, then provide the changed event on it.

This is the code that i found while browsing one of the MSDN Forums:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a56ac5c1-e71f-4a12-bbfa-ab8fc7b36f1c/datagridview-text-changed?forum=winformsdatacontrols

I am also adding the code here:

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)

{

   if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
   {

      TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Control;
      tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
   }
}

void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
{
   MessageBox.Show("changed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to update the value without changing cells (as in on the fly), you'll have to handle the [DataGridView.KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event and check for which cell is being updated.

If that's too much of a hassle, use the [DataGridView.CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) event. It's simpler to implement than the KeyPress event.