# Populate other Cells while Another Cell is being Editted

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

What I'm trying to do is (just an example), while typing in dgv row 0, col 0, if the value = 10 then dgv row 0, col 1 = Yes. But if dgv row 0, col 0 value = 100 then dgv row 0, col 1 = No.

I want this to run while I'm typing, so dgv row 0, col 1 could display several different values before I'm finished with row 0, col 0.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm finding it hard to explain. Properly why I've been unable to find an answer on the web.

I've trying the cellvaluechanged event, but that only changes row 0, col 1 once I've exited row 0 , col 0 and not while I'm typing.
And have also try the editiingcontrolshowing event, but I'm unable to get the events row and col index. If I could figure out how to get the row and col index, i think I might be able to get this one to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question is a duplicate.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7226872/2319909

TL;DR DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged and DataGridView.CellValueChanged events

```
Private Sub YourDGV_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If YourDGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = rateColumnIndex Then
        YourDGV.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub YourDGV_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If e.ColumnIndex = rateColumnIndex Then
        Dim cellAmount As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = YourDGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(amountColumnIndex)
        Dim cellQty As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = YourDGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(qtyColumnIndex)
        Dim cellRate As DataGridViewTextBoxCell = YourDGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(rateColumnIndex)
        cellAmount.Value = CInt(cellQty.Value) * CInt(cellRate.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using `EditingControlShowing` event.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

    Try
        RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyUp, AddressOf UpdateAnotherColumnOnKeyUp
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    If Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyUp, AddressOf UpdateAnotherColumnOnKeyUp
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateAnotherColumnOnKeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)

    With DataGridView1.CurrentCell

        Dim blnAnotherColumnValue As Boolean = False

        If CType(sender, TextBox).Text = 10 Then
            blnAnotherColumnValue = True
        End If

        DataGridView1.Rows(.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = blnAnotherColumnValue

    End With

End Sub
```