# DataGridView Cell Value Changing

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-framework-version

Is there any way to get the datagridview cell value when changing?

I have a datagridview with 5 columns such as Invoice number, Invoice Date, Invoice For, Qty, Rate, Unit Price.

When i changing the qty or rate, application needs to multiplies the qty and rate and put it them into Unit Price cell.

I have already tried with CellValueChanged with CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged. But it end edit the cell value of my current editing cell's data. which cause that unable to enter further data into that cell.

[Cell Value Changing Event ,c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820672/cell-value-changing-event-c)

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: have u tried CellEndEdit?

Comment: yes i did.. but it reflects after only the focus comes out from the current cell.

Comment: can u show me ur code that u've used in CellValueChanged with CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

Comment: please give some example code. i work massivly with all of these events without any problem. Is your datagridview databound?

Comment: please have a look at this site, maybe it helps you to understand the different events: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240221/DataGridView-Event-Sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try cell validating event with cell value changed event.